# PHP not executing on main file (index.php)

Tags: php, iis

I have new server with IIS 10 and PHP on it (FastCGI). When I type full address (e. g. domain.com/index.php) everything is fine. But when I'm using short address (only domain.com) browser trying to download file without name (but when I save it, it is my index.php) - not executing PHP.

Have anyone idea why? Where can I search reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

Check `<defaultDocument>` element on ApplicationHost.config file. If "index.php" is not included add it.

Comment: I have Index.php there

Comment: Can you check the handlers in _web.config_? Is there a handler for PHP or CGI or some combination?